# Grunt Locales- Manually Translation Required?

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, gruntjs

I need my app internationalized and have setting grunt-locales. Simply by adding the data-localize directive the text inside should be translated. My initConfig is configured as such-

```
locales: {
  options: {
    locales: ['en_US', 'de_DE']
  },
  update: {
    src: 'app/views/*.html',
    dest: 'app/js/locales/{locale}/i18n.json'
  },
  build: {
     src: 'app/js/locales/**/i18n.json',
     dest: 'app/js/locales/{locale}/i18n.js'
  },
  'export': {
    src: 'app/js/locales/**/i18n.json',
    dest: 'app/js/locales/{locale}/i18n.csv'
  },
  'import': {
    src: 'app/js/locales/**/i18n.csv',
    dest: 'app/js/locales/{locale}/i18n.json'
  }
},
```

And data-localized is used in one case in the app here-

```
<a href="#" data-localize>Forgot your username or password?</a>
```

What that's done when grunt locales are built is create this file under app/js/locales/de_DE/i18n.json

```
{
  "Forgot your username or password?": "Forgot your username or password?"
}
```

Which I don't have to tell you is not translated. So will I need to go through and translate this for every language or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, grunt-locales is a tool used for extracting the necessary information from your templates and js files to build the above json objects for all locales that the developer specifies.  You will need a translator to go through and translate the strings within the json objects.

Once they have done so, you simply re-build the i18n.json files to create i18n.js files using grunt locales:build.  The i18n.js files are used by the localize directive service and filters.

Very late answer, but if you are still interested I hope this helps.